# Skyrim Console: Is there a command the opposite of PRID?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

FOR USE IN BAT FILES I need to deselect whatever is selected.

I know that for example `prid 14` will select the player. Is there a command to deselect in this context?

`prid`, `prid 0`, and `prid 14` again don't work.

I'm moving the player around in a custom situation. I had been using the little map flags as markers and using a bat to do `player.moveto`  the flag, but that has a couple problems. What I wanted to do is `unprid`, `tcl`, `prid 14`, `setpos <coords>`, `unprid`... since tcl doesn't work if something is selected, I wanted to contain the entire thing from soup to nuts into a bat file.

However, I've discovered since posting this that `prid` in bat files doesn't work. It's ignored. So any `unprid` is likely to be as well.

What's close is to `tcl` ahead of time, and without `prid` just do `player.setpos` which is working ok, but will eventually become problematic.

Comment: May i ask why you want to deselect a target? Maybe theres a workaround for your problem

Comment: @Tyrmos I modded the op.

Comment: Can you not do `XXAABB.moveto player` instead of `prid XXAABB` followed by `moveto player`?

Comment: @LoreFriendly you've misunderstood. I need to unselect (de`prid`)  whatever is selected in order for `tcl` to work. I was using player as an example. If I watned to just move stuff, that's not a problem, but activating `tcl` from a bat file can't be guaranteed unless I can un`prid`. I'm pretty sure it can't be done.

Comment: @monsto I can not verify ATM but maybe prid null?

Comment: "Skyrim Key Helper is an optional program that will easily let you bind any key or mouse button to any available command." https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/88/? - **you need a console command for RMB**. Never tried it, GL.

Answer (score 1):

See the following from the UESP wiki:

> Many commands are targeted: this means that you may use player.command to affect the player character; for example, type player.setav carryweight 1000 will set the Player's Carry Weight at 1000. Or, you may want to target the NPC/actor, by first typing prid , Enter. Then, type the command by itself, setav carryweight 1000, to affect the NPC, specified by  (Note: including the zeroes at the beginning of the RefID when targeting NPCs may produce a "command not found" error. That can be evaded though by placing the RefID in quotes, e.g. "000A2C94".setav carryweight 1000 will set Lydia's Carry Weight at 1000).

https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#General_Information

I tried it for a command I was running on game load using script dragon, and it worked like a charm.  Just put quotes around your object ID and it will allow the use of targeted commands with dot syntax.

Comment: To be clear, I am fairly certain it needs to be double quotes.  I recently attempted to do this again, and it failed to work with single quotes.  Unfortunately I did not think to use double quotes or confirm the ID was correct before fixing the concern correctly with a quick remove in TES5Edit, so perhaps we will need someone to confirm this still behaves as I originally reported.